# Best way to execute sql command in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqlcmd

I need to do some sql query against sql-server 2008 R2. The command is:

```
C:> sqlcmd –S
.\APPSDB
1> use
Example_database
2> go
1> Select SiteName, SiteID, Platform, Description, AdminUser from dbo.ExampleInfo
2> go
```

I want to develop a console application in C# to run this query. My question is: What is the appropriate way to do it? Should I put the above command into a SQL script and use a process to execute this script, or should I use stand C# SQL API such as `SqlConnection` to do it? Something like:

```
string cmdStr = @"....." //the above command
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = cmdStr;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            do
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {             
                    Console.WriteLine(reader["SiteName"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(reader["SiteName"].ToString());
                    // the rest
                }
            Console.WriteLine("--next command--");
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a choice you need to make.  If this app begins to grow (as we all know most apps do) you should use an sql connection object and call a sproc.  Otherwise a script is fine.

Comment: why downvote my qustion? I have several databases under one sql server instance APPSDB.

Comment: @JonH meh; sprocs can be over-rated ; parameterized SQL is perfectly appropriate in most cases

Comment: @eric the only thing you need in the CommandText is the "select ..."

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `sqlcmd` for this.

The `CommandText` property should contain the query only like this:

```
string cmdStr = @"Select SiteName, SiteID, Platform, Description, AdminUser 
                  from dbo.ExampleInfo";
```

Comment: I have several databases under one sql server instance. I think I need to use "Use Example_Database", or "Use_Example_Database1", etc. single cmdStr may not work.

Comment: @ericyoung This should be in the connection string, provided in the connection string property.

Comment: @eric you shouldn't need that at all: that belogs in the connection string